# Codeigniter Installation Issue

Tags: codeigniter

I am new to Codeigniter framework. I just installed CodeIgniter and also "NodCms" CMS. "NodCms" install was complete, but that browser page returns

> "404 Page Not Found"

and

> "The page you requested was not found."

How to fix that issue?

Comment: You should put this question in Issues line of repository.

Comment: Can you tell us what is you do before 404 ? Like, Installing CodeIgniter and run well print welcome, but after install NodCMS become 404. then what code you was changed. If you want a good answers, please provide a good question.

Comment: it seems there are several versions of NodCMS on GitHub, which one are you using?